# Attach an EventHandler Defined in One Class to an Element Defined in a Different Class

Tags: c#, wpf, events

Searched around for syntax but couldn't find anything. What I have is an event handler defined in my main file and i want to attach that to an element I am creating in a different class. I know the syntax for adding an event handler which is inside the class is

```
element.PreviewMouseDown += EventHandlerName;
```

but I'm not sure what the syntax is for adding a handler that's in a seperate class. I tried

```
element.PreviewMouseDown += MainWindow.EventHandlerName;
```

but that is invalid. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a reference to the instance you want to receive the handler. You cannot refer to the class itself (unless the handler is a static method):

```cs
void Main()
{
    var a = new A();
    var b = new B();

    a.Event += b.Handler; // reference to instance method
}

class A
{
    public event EventHandler Event;
}

class B
{
    public void Handler(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

    }
}
```

If you do have a static handler, this is what it would look like:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var a = new A();

    a.Event += B.Handler; // reference to a static method
}

class A
{
    public event EventHandler Event;
}

class B
{
    public static void Handler(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for